# How to get number of miliseconds since epoch in ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying hard to get Unix Timestamp for current time in ADF. Basically I need number of number of milliseconds (ms) since epoch. I tried dabbling with built-in ticks function in ADF but it's not what I need. Also the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#ticks) on the ticks is not really clear. It says number of ticks since specified timestamp is what the function returns. 1 tick = 100 nanoseconds & 1000000 nanoseconds = 1 ms. So considering this, I used the following expression in set variable activity:-

```
@{ div(ticks('1970-01-01T00:00:00.0000000Z'),10000)   }
```

So the expectation is that whenever I run it, it should give me number of milliseconds since the epoch ( up to the moment of execution ) -- so by this definition every time I run it, it should return me a different value. But it returns a fixed value 62135568000000 every time I run it. So either the documentation is not correct or it's not really calculating what I really need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Function ticks() return the number of ticks from '0001-01-01T00:00:00.0000000Z' to parameter of ticks(), not from '1970-01-01T00:00:00.0000000Z'.This is why you always get a fixed value 62135568000000.

I have tried `@{ticks('0001-01-01T00:00:00.0000000Z')}`, result is 0.

[image]

So if you want to get ms from '1970-01-01T00:00:00.0000000Z' to current time, you can try this:`@{div(sub(ticks(utcnow()),ticks('1970-01-01T00:00:00.0000000Z')),10000)}`.