# Combine Date and Time in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: timestamp, type-conversion, azure-data-factory

I have two Columns. One Date Column and one Time Column.

ADF reads my Source Data like this.
DateColumn: 2022-01-01 (Date format)

TimeColumn: 1899-12-31T05:59:59.000Z (String Format)

In an old Use Case without ADF I was able to convert the Columns into Numbers, and add them to get a timestamp with the date and the time.

I don't know how to handle the Timestamp in ADF, every approach leads to only Null Values.

Comment: Can you provide the expected result as per your input columns? and are you using dataflows, right?

Comment: Are you using Copy, Data Flows, or another pipeline activity type?

Comment: Tick function can be helpful in your case: Please check this query posted by other user: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64193542/how-to-get-number-of-miliseconds-since-epoch-in-adf#:~:text=Function%20ticks()%20return%20the,get%20a%20fixed%20value%2062135568000000.

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced the above and got below results in Dataflow.

This is my sample input:

[image]

As you already had a date in the time column, when you try to combine the above it will null values only.

So, try to combine and form the result column from the time stamp time column(**split from T**) like below.

```
toTimestamp(concat(toString(date),'T',split(time,'T')[2]), 'yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss')
```

**Result in Derived column:**

[image]